# Choosing multiple columns and changing their classes using a lookup table in R?

Tags: r, class, multiple-columns

Is it possible to use a lookup table to assign/change the classes of variables in a data frame in R? I have thousands of columns with messed up classes in one data frame (my_df), and list of what they should be in another data frame (my_lt). PSEUDO CODE I was thinking something like use my_lt$variable_name and grep() on colnames(my_df) and pass the output through as.numeric if lt$variable_class == "numeric", with some form of if..else. Any help would be much appreciated!

input - my data frame (my_df)

```
my_df = data.frame(q1_hight_1=c(12,31,22,12),q1_hight_2=c(24,54,23,32),q1_hight_3=c(34,23,65,34),q2_shoe_size_1=c(2,2,3,4),q2_shoe_size_2=c(4,3,3,4))
```

input - my lookup table (my_lt)

```
my_lt = data.frame(variable_name=c("hight","shoe_size"),variable_class=c("numeric","integer"))
```

desired output (when checking classes)

```
$q1_hight_1 [1] "numeric" $q1_hight_2 [1] "numeric" $q1_hight_3 [1] "numeric" $q2_shoe_size_1 [1] "integer" $q2_shoe_size_2 [1] "integer"
```

Comment: You could probably use `mapply` and a switch statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does the trick, given that there's no trap in the names you give to your variables (I use a very naïve grep).

```
library(dplyr)
library(purr)
map2(as.character(my_lt$variable_name),
    as.character(my_lt$variable_class),
    function(nam,cl){ map(grep(nam,names(my_df)),function(i){class(my_df[[i]]) <<- cl})})

str(my_df)
# 'data.frame': 4 obs. of  5 variables:
#  $ q1_hight_1    : num  12 31 22 12
#  $ q1_hight_2    : num  24 54 23 32
#  $ q1_hight_3    : num  34 23 65 34
#  $ q2_shoe_size_1: int  2 2 3 4
#  $ q2_shoe_size_2: int  4 3 3 4
```